# ColdFusion convert query to XML

Tags: xml, coldfusion

The code below generates XML items from a query just fine, but everything I add it to the API I get a parse error and I don't know where I'm going wrong.

```
<cfsavecontent variable="getlineitems">
    <cfoutput query="ccitems">    
    <cfset idreset = (#currentrow# - 1) />
    <item id="#idreset#">
        <unitPrice>#Trim(XMLFormat(ccitems.unitprice))#</unitPrice>
        <quantity>#Trim(XMLFormat(ccitems.quantity))#</quantity>
        <productname>#Trim(XMLFormat(ccitems.productname))#</productname>
        <taxAmount>#Trim(XMLFormat(ccitems.taxamount))#</taxAmount>
        <totalAmount>#Trim(XMLFormat(ccitems.totalamount))#</totalAmount>
        <grossNetIndicator>N</grossNetIndicator>
        <taxRate>#Trim(XMLFormat(ccitems.taxrate))#</taxRate>
        <productCode>801418</productCode>
        <unitOfMeasure>each</unitOfMeasure>
        <commodityCode>801418</commodityCode>
        <dutyAmount>0.00</dutyAmount>
        <discountAmount>0</discountAmount>
        <discountIndicator>N</discountIndicator>
    </item>
    </cfoutput>
</cfsavecontent>
<cfdump var="#getlineitems#" />
<cfabort />
```

Comment: can you add a final xml structure that you are tryin to pass to the API?

Comment: also the api call code.

Comment: Please include a snippet of the XML where the parse error occurs, and specify exactly where the parse error is. Most XML renderers will tell you where the parse error is.

Comment: FWIW, if you're CF > 9, you should use `encodeForXML()` instead of `XMLFormat()`. It handles a larger range of character encoding.

Comment: Where are you adding `<?xml version = "1.0"?>`?

Comment: It was an ID10T issue on my part. I passed a field that depended on another field to work. Sorry for the false alarm, but thanks for coming to my aid. I haven't touched CF in over 5 years so bare with me.

Comment: You should write what you changed so that someone else can see how you fixed it.

Comment: And please trim before encoding. Otherwise whitespaces might be encoded, so trimming won't do anything.

Answer (score 0):

```
<!--- Replace XMLFormat with encodeForXML as Adobe recommends --->
<cfsavecontent variable="getlineitems">
    <cfoutput query="ccitems">    
    <cfset idreset = currentrow - 1 />
    <item id="#idreset#">
        <unitPrice>#Trim(encodeForXML(ccitems.unitprice))#</unitPrice>
        <quantity>#Trim(encodeForXML(ccitems.quantity))#</quantity>
        <productname>#Trim(encodeForXML(ccitems.productname))#</productname>
        <taxAmount>#Trim(encodeForXML(ccitems.taxamount))#</taxAmount>
        <totalAmount>#Trim(encodeForXML(ccitems.totalamount))#</totalAmount>
        <grossNetIndicator>N</grossNetIndicator>
        <taxRate>#Trim(encodeForXML(ccitems.taxrate))#</taxRate>
        <productCode>801418</productCode>
        <unitOfMeasure>each</unitOfMeasure>
        <commodityCode>801418</commodityCode>
        <dutyAmount>0.00</dutyAmount>
        <discountAmount>0</discountAmount>
        <discountIndicator>N</discountIndicator>
    </item>
    </cfoutput>
</cfsavecontent>

<!--- Add the the XML declaration and the root element (which I have assumed is called 'ccitems')--->
<cfset xmlString='<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>' & '<ccitems>' & getlineitems & '</ccitems>'>

<!--- Optionally, if you're dealing with a ColdFusion API, you might need to convert the XML string to an XML object--->   
<cfset xmlDocument=xmlParse(xmlString)>  

<cfdump var="#xmlDocument#" />
<cfabort />
```